# What happened to "Mobility Package 1" (new EU lorry driver regulations)?

Tags: european-union, legislation, transportation

After many news pieces covering [protest](https://www.euronews.com/2019/01/11/eastern-european-truckers-protest-against-eu-mobility-package) of Eastern EU firms/drivers and [some](https://www.europeandatajournalism.eu/eng/News/Data-news/Putting-the-brakes-on-East-European-mobility) on subsequent parliamentary exhortations, I can't figure out what if anything was adopted from "Mobility Package 1" and if it was still has the opposition of the Eastern EU firms (if not drivers).

The general idea (that was objected to) was that it required Eastern Europe drivers to return home much more often, as they often spent months on the road in Western Europe.

So what if anything came of the proposals to limit/regulate this?

Comment: As I understand it, the rule would require firms to pay drivers operating in the western part of the EU the minimum wages applicable in the west. This "return home" would only apply if they try to dodge the minimum wage.

Comment: I don't know the answers, but this may be useful to one who can answer. [Mobility Package: Questions and Answers](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/road/mobility-package-questions-and-answers_en).